# reverse proxy two locations, one nested inside the other

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two server programs on a machine. One's listening at localhost:3000, and the other at localhost:3001. The second one is an API server, and the first delivers web pages.

I want to use nginx as a reverse proxy in such a way that incoming requests to URIs like this

```
https://example.com/api/what/ever
```

are redirected to the second server as `http://localhost:3001/what/ever`, and URIs like this

```
https://example.com/ and https://example.com/some/route/what/ever
```

are redirected to the first server as

```
http://localhost:3000/ and http://localhost:3000/some/route/what/ever
```

In other words, I want to pick off the `example.com/api/*` requests to send to the second server, and send the rest to the first server.

But, it works as if my `/api/` location directive is not present: everything's getting passed to the first server, which of course responds 404 to the api requests, and normally to other requests.

Here's my nginx.conf attempt.

```
          location ^~ /hub/  {
            rewrite ^/hub(.*)$ $1 last;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          }

          location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          }
```

I also tried `location ~ ^(?!/api).*$ {` for the second location directive, using a regex in an attempt to make it not match my /api/ URIs, with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `last` keyword on a `rewrite` statement causes Nginx to restart the search for a location to process the rewritten URI. Your `rewrite...last` statement sends the request to the other location block.

To process the rewritten URI within the same `location` block, use `break` instead. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /hub/ {
    rewrite ^/hub(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, the same translation can be achieved by appending an optional URI to the value in the `proxy_pass` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /hub/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your second suggestion worked great (so did the first one, but I like simple).